# Get substring using either perl or sed

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I can't seem to get a substring correctly.

```
declare BRANCH_NAME="bugfix/US3280841-something-duh";

# Trim it down to "US3280841"
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's/\(^.*\)\/[a-z0-9]\|[A-Z0-9]\+/\1/g')
```

That still returns `bugfix/US3280841-something-duh`.

If I try an use perl instead:

```
declare BRANCH_NAME="bugfix/US3280841-something-duh";

# Trim it down to "US3280841"
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | perl -nle 'm/^.*\/([a-z0-9]|[A-Z0-9])+/; print $1');
```

That outputs nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's~^.*/|-.*$~~g' <<< "$BRANCH_NAME"
```

```
US3280841
```

Ot this `awk`:

```
awk -F '[/-]' '{print $2}' <<< "$BRANCH_NAME"
```

```
US3280841
```

Answer (score 6):

Using bash parameter expansion only:

```
$: # don't use caps; see below.
$: declare branch="bugfix/US3280841-something-duh"
$: tmp="${branch##*/}"
$: echo "$tmp"
US3280841-something-duh
$: trimmed="${tmp%%-*}" 
$: echo "$trimmed"
US3280841
```

Which means:

```
$: tmp="${branch_name##*/}"
$: trimmed="${tmp%%-*}"
```

does the job in two steps without spawning extra processes.

In `sed`,

```
$: sed -E 's#^.*/([^/-]+)-.*$#\1#' <<< "$branch"
```

This says "after any or no characters followed by a slash, remember one or more that are not slashes or dashes, followed by a not-remembered dash and then any or no characters, then replace the whole input with the remembered part."

Your original pattern was

```
's/\(^.*\)\/[a-z0-9]\|[A-Z0-9]\+/\1/g'
```

This says "remember any number of anything followed by a slash, then a lowercase letter or a digit, then a pipe character (because those only work with -E), then a capital letter or digit, then a literal plus sign, and then replace it all with what you remembered."

GNU's [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is your friend. I look stuff up all the time to make sure I'm doing it right. Sometimes it still takes me a few tries, lol.

An aside - try not to use all-capital variable names. That is a convention that indicates it's special to the OS, like RANDOM or IFS.

Comment: Upvoted your answer because I generally like to avoid calling `sed` et al for what should be simple string transformations. Still, it bothers me that `bash` doesn't provide an easy one-liner way to do a regex substitution on a variable. The best I could come up with for a one-liner in `bash` is the very ugly `branch=$([[ "$branch" =~ ^.*/([^-]+)-.*$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")`. I wish `bash` would give us something similar to `perl`'s `$s =~ s/pattern/subst/;`, but `bash`'s `${parameter/pattern/subst}` expansion AFAIK doesn't speak regex.

Comment: You *could* just type it as `tmp="${branch##*/}" && trimmed="${tmp%%-*}"`. but yeah. I understand it, but I agree.

Comment: Yeah it's not just about cramming it all into one *line*. It's that what should ideally be one *operation* requires multiple operations in bash.

Comment: For the record, you can accomplish a helluva *LOT* by combining `${parameter/pattern/subst}` with `shopt -s extglob`; the real limitation is that it's always anchored at both ends. =o/

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's:[^/]*/\([^-]*\)-.*:\1:'<<<"bugfix/US3280841-something-duh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl version just has `+` in wrong place. It should be inside the capture brackets:

```
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | perl -nle 'm/^.*\/([a-z0-9A-Z]+)/; print $1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `^` before `A-Z0-9`

```
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed -e 's/\(^.*\)\/[a-z0-9]\|[^A-Z0-9]\+/\1/g')
```

in your `sed` case.

Alternatively and briefly, you can use

```
TRIMMED=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | sed "s/[a-z\/\-]//g" )
```

too.

Answer (score 0):

type on shell terminal

```
$ BRANCH_NAME="bugfix/US3280841-something-duh"

$ echo $BRANCH_NAME| perl -pe 's/.*\/(\w\w[0-9]+).+/\1/'
```

use s (substitute) command instead of m (match)
perl is a superset of sed so it'd be identical 'sed -E' instead of 'perl -pe'

Answer (score 0):

Another variant using *Perl Regular Expression Character Classes* (see [`perldoc perlrecharclass`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)).

```
echo $BRANCH_NAME | perl -nE 'say m/^.*\/([[:alnum:]]+)/;'
```